# Best way to validate semantics with xtext

Tags: java, validation, dsl, xtext, xtend

i'm new at Xtext validation system, and can't figure out how to validade my expressions.

I have something like:

```
   VAR
      <VARIABLE>:<TYPE>:= <VALUE>;
   END_VAR
```

What i need to do is ensure that <'TYPE'> is the same type as <'VALUE'>.
My grammar rules are setup like this snippet:

```
VarRule:
   'VAR' 
     variableDef+=VariableDefRule+ ';'
   'END_VAR'
;
VariableDefRule:
  type=TypeName (':=' constant=Constant)?
;
TypeName:
  INT | STRING | FLOAT
;

INT: name='INT';
STRING: name='STRING';
FLOAT: name='FLOAT';

Constant:
  Integer | String | ...
;
terminal Integer returns ecore::EInt:
 (0..9)+
;
```

How can i associate the <'VALUE'> element to a TypeName element?

Answer (score 2):

what you are looking for is a typesystem. there are several ways of achieving this: you write your own one (by writing checks in the validator class), you use existing ones like http://xsemantics.sourceforge.net/ or https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/xtext-typesystem/

you may have a look at Lorenzo Bettinis Book 'Implementing Domain-Specific Languages with Xtext and Xtend'

Comment: [Lorenzo's book](http://www.lorenzobettini.it/tag/dsl/) is indeed highly recommendable.